# Validation function nested in another function not running

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am creating a simple questionnaire where a user will answer all the questions and get answers calculated based on point values assigned to the response. A JavaScript function then calculates and displays the results on screen.

The calculation and responses work just fine, but I would like the form to put up an alert if all the questions haven't been answered (right now it just doesn't run the function). I have all the questions set with the "required" attribute, but nothing currently comes up to show that a required question has not been answered. It just doesn't run the function.

Right now I have a little validation function that should run when the user hits submit and if everything is check it will call the main function to calculate the results:

```
function validateForm() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByTagName('input[type="radio"]');

    for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
          GetRadio();
      }
        else{
            alert("You must answer all of the questions.");
        }
    }
}

function GetRadio() {

var QS1 = document.querySelector('input[name = "radio1"]:checked').value,
    QS2 = document.querySelector('input[name = "radio2"]:checked').value,
    QS3 = document.querySelector('input[name = "radio3"]:checked').value,
    QS4 = document.querySelector('input[name = "radio4"]:checked').value,
    QS5 = document.querySelector('input[name = "radio5"]:checked').value;

selfPoints = Number(QS1) + Number(QS2) + Number(QS3) + Number(QS4) + Number(QS5);...
```

My expectation is that it should then run the validation before going on to run the rest of the function to calculate results, and put up the Alert box if any are left blank. Instead it doesn't run anything. Not all the questions are answered so it can't calculate, but it isn't putting up an alert either.

***Update***

OK, the updated code didn't want to work, but the first suggestion of using the querySelectorAll in my original code started working. (I must have done something differently the second time around but I have no clue what) so this is what I've got now:

```
function validateForm() {
    var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

    for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
          GetRadio();
      }
        else{
            alert("You must answer all of the questions.");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works, it puts up the alert and it will dismiss the alert, but now it's throwing up the alert even if all the questions are answered, and then when I dismiss it, it calculates my results. Why isn't it just running the GetRadio() function to calculate when all the boxes are checked?

***Update 2***

Alright, the code as it stands:

```
  function validateForm() {
    var radios = [document.getElementsByName("radio1"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio2"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio3"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio4"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio5"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio1-2"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio2-2"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio3-2"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio4-2"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio5-2"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio1-3"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio2-3"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio3-3"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio4-3"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio5-3"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio1-4"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio2-4"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio3-4"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio4-4"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio5-4"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio1-5"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio2-5"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio3-5"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio4-5"),
                 document.getElementsByName("radio5-5"),];

    for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (!radios[i].checked) {
            alert("You must answer all of the questions.");
            return;
        }
    }
    GetRadio();
}
```

It pulls the groups, but it looks like it still wants all the radio buttons to be selected before it will run the calculation. Even if there is an answer in for each group of radios I get the alert. What is the right way to say just one of the radios in each group needs to be checked?

Comment: where do you call validateForm() ? And why do you want to run GetRadio() multiple times?

Comment: validateForm() is called when the user submits the form. I don't want to call GetRadio() multiple times. I want it to call it only if all the questions have been answered.

Comment: I recommend that you use console.log() to inspect the results of each line in the code you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`document.getElementsByTagName('input[type="radio"]')`

to

`document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')`

Also try changing the validate function like below

```
function validateForm() {
  var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]')
  if (!radios.filter(radio => !radio.checked).length) {
    GetRadio();
  } else {
    alert("You must answer all of the questions.");
  }
})
```

Comment: I still don't get an alert if questions are left unanswered.

Comment: Now try with the updated function I've updated in my answer

Comment: OK, right so the alert is coming up, but now it won't go away when I click OK on the box so that I can go back and answer the questions.

Comment: is there a common class name on the parent of each radio group

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues with your code (and with the updated code).

The first issue that the other people seem to have missed is that the updated code continues as soon as it finds any value is selected for any question - **it does not check that all individual questions have an answer as expected**.

The second issue, is that **the current code stops as soon as any radio is unchecked** (so the very first element), without checking if another answer from the same question is chosen instead.

**The solution** is to group the answers within a question and to check one question at a time. Structure your HTML like the following, **to group radios**:

```
<input type="radio" name="Question1" value="a"> A
<input type="radio" name="Question1" value="b"> B
<input type="radio" name="Question1" value="c"> C

<input type="radio" name="Question2" value="a"> A
<input type="radio" name="Question2" value="b"> B
<input type="radio" name="Question2" value="c"> C
```

Then **valid each question** like this:

```
if (!document.querySelector('input[name="Question1"]:checked').value) {
    //If nothing is checked, it will get undefined
    return false;
}
```

So the **complete loop looks like this**:

```
//This part is the answer to your question
for (var i=1; i <= questions.length;i++) {
    if (!document.querySelector('input[name="Question"' + i + ']:checked').value) {
        //If nothing is checked, it will get undefined and false will be returned
        return false;
    }
}
```

As a **bonus**, you can check the results the same way:

```
function checkAnswer(questionNumber, correctAnswer) {
    let checkedItem = document.querySelector('input[name="Question"' + questionNumber + ']:checked');
    if (checkedItem.value === correctAnswer) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

    //OR
    // return checkedItem.value === correctAnswer
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly, your code should look like this:
If any check wrong, raise alert, exit and don't even calculate
If all checked then calculate

```
function validateQuestion(container) {
    var radios = container.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (radios[i].checked) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}

function validateForm() {
  var questions = document. querySelectorAll('.question');
  var isValid = true;
  for (var i = 0, len = questions.length; i < len; i++) {
    isValid = isValid && validateQuestion(questions[i]);
    if (!isValid) {
      alert("You must answer all of the questions.");
      return;
    }
  }
  GetRadio();
}
```

You question html should look like this

```
<div class="question q-1">
  Question 1:
  <input type="radio" value="1-a">A
  <input type="radio" value="1-b">B
  <input type="radio" value="1-c">C
</div>
<div class="question q-2">
  Question 2:
  <input type="radio" value="2-a">A
  <input type="radio" value="2-b">B
  <input type="radio" value="2-c">C
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what it should do. I tried that, but I checked them all and I got the alert and it never went to calculate.

Comment: @CarynMay You should console.log your radios list. you may got a hidden radio or in another form. Better lomit scope of it `document.querySelectorAll('.yourform input[type="radio"]');`

Comment: OK, so I think I know what it's doing. The questionnaire has a question and three options. It needs to check that at least one option is picked for each question. There should be 25. The array I'm getting from querySelectorAll has 75. It's expecting all the radio buttons to be selected. It needs to just check for one radio button per question...I'm not sure how to simply say that...

Comment: Correct! Then you must find away to count per group of question. Not all of them